# Running .\gradlew createDebugCoverageReport causes java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionErrorUnsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, test-coverage

I went through all the questions on stack and other sites for following error, but I am still not able to resolve it. 
I also did Invalidate Cache and restarted Android Studio
I am using JDK 1.8, my Java_HOME path is set to 1.8 and embedded JDK checkbox is checked.
I am using latest Android Studio and `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`

Following is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2"
        classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 26

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = "1.0.2"
    butterKnifeVersion = "8.8.1"
    greenDaoVersion = "3.2.2"
    swipeLayoutVersion = "1.2.0"
    rxjavaVersion = '2.1.7'
    rxandroidVersion = '2.0.1'
    rxjacva2ExtensionsVersion = '0.18.1'

    // Test dependencies
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '2.11.0'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
    runnerVersion = '1.0.1'
    rulesVersion = '1.0.1'
    espressoVersion = '3.0.1'
    powerMockito = '2.0.0-beta.5'
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: @Jens I know but none of the answers worked for me. i l already said i went through all the questions relating to it

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to

```
supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.0'
```

Reduce to 26 and check.

Support library should match with the compileSdkVersion.

TargetSDK and compileSDK Version also should match.

There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

**Sometime It might be due to the thirdaprty library which added in the gradle doesn't support java 1.8
You need to cross check the libraries and supported JDK version.**

Comment: Please maintain targetsdk and compile sdk same , in your case 26.

Comment: I am getting clean project error when i change it to 26
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preMockDebugBuild'. > Failed to create parent directory 'E:\Work\Android\Lea\app\build' when creating directory 'E:\Work\Android\Lea\app\build\intermediates\prebuild\mock\debug'

Comment: Did u cross-checked the libraries which u added which support JDK 1.8?   Or else try to use the very latest version third party libraries.

Comment: I am using all latest version of third-party libraries, how do i cross-check the libraries support 1.8?

Comment: Which is the swipelayout library?

Comment: com.daimajia.swipelayout:library